# SVG sprite not working/displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Alright, so I have an SVG sprite that I want to place in my HTML.

```
<svg class="icon-minus"><use xlink:href="#icon-minus"></use></svg>
```

It has this as CSS (stylus):

```
.icon-minus
    display: inline-block
    width: 1em
    height: 1em
    fill: black
```

Te SVG itself is in the HTML also (placed near the bottom of  but not all the way, contained in a div):

```
<svg style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0;" width="0" height="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
    <symbol id="icon-minus" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <title>minus</title>
        <path class="path1" d="M3 11h18q0.414 0 0.707 0.293t0.293 0.707-0.293 0.707-0.707 0.293h-18q-0.414 0-0.707-0.293t-0.293-0.707 0.293-0.707 0.707-0.293z"></path>
    </symbol>
</defs>
```

It may be important to know that the the entirety of this is injected using jQuery .load, so it's not there on initial page load. This includes both the SVG and the SVG markup. They are injected together.

The SVG is not visible onscreen.

Comment: Can you post your method on how the markup is injected? The markup as it stands displays the SVG fine. http://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/pen/22b4c08d693c6001a35a1c92f775f4d0

Comment: @JamieButtonsCoulter https://gist.github.com/anonymous/81e27abb9dffdc4038add17603f5f4bf